# Получение только что добавленной строки

Tags: php, sql

Всем привет. Имеется вот такой код, как можно получить ID только что добавленной записи в таблицу?

```
        if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
    $room = $_POST['room'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    $db->execute("
        insert into `rooms` (`name`,`password`)
        values ('$room','$password')
    ");

    header('Location: /chat.php?room=' . ##### ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ ЗДЕСЬ ######;

}
```

В коде указал место где требуется использовать. Но, получать его путем `select * from '$таблица' where name='$room';` нельзя, так как имена комнат могут совпадать, по этому нужно получать ID записи другим способом, при этом учитывая, что запрашивать просто последнею добавленную запись в таблицу тоже некорректно, так как в это время может быть создана другая комната и все перепутается в кашу.

Comment: Советую почитать про SQL инъекции и то как с ними бороться

Comment: @MrClon про них читал, в курсе. Интересует именно ответ на вопрос, который задал, код показан вкратце для наглядности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение вашей проблемы, если у вас PDO, после выполнения команды на вставку:

```
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Если Mysqli, то тогда:

```
$id = $db->insert_id;
```

Здесь подобных вопросов на указанную тему очень много, воспользуйтесь поиском перед публикацией вопроса.

Comment: Попробовал добавить новую функцию к своему классу
'
  public function __construct($host, $user, $password, $db) {
   $this->connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);
  }

  public function lastInsertId() {
   return $this->connection->lastInsertId();
  }
'
В итоге получаю сообщение об ошибке: 
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::lastInsertId() in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost2\core\db.php on line 45`

Comment: Код: ` public function __construct($host, $user, $password, $db) { $this->connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db); } public function lastInsertId() { return $this->connection->lastInsertId(); } `
Ошибка: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::lastInsertId() in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost2\core\db.php on line 45`

Пытался показать код наглядно,  в итоге все сбилось. И сообщение почему то не редактируется уже.

Comment: @Bek1zo а, у вас mysqli, тогда после execute просто $db->insert_id, думал PDO

Comment: Все бы ничего, но запрос выводит "Null".

Comment: @Bek1zo в коде execute на query поменяйте.

Comment: Теперь это стало выглядеть так:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::query() in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost2\chat.php on line 11`

Comment: @Bekzo А что у вас за класс такой Database? Если это класс фреймворка, то читайте документацию к нему, как получить last insert id

Comment: Класс сделал сам и добавил туда функции получение/внесения в таблицу данных.

Comment: Проблема решена добавлением функции `insert_id;` в класс. Спасибо.